# opengl glTranslatef() concept

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to OpenGl ES. I was studying a tutorial for opengles in android where for shape movement, glTranslatef() was used. My questions is simple. First tell me whether this function is used for zooming purpose as I have seen if I am not wrong, by using -z value, the object goes into deep into screen.
Second, if I have drawn a square and then used function glTranslatef(0,0,-3) and draw again a new square. Will this function call will effect the square previously drawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the glTranslatef() function is one way to achieve the effect of zooming by changing the -z value, although the effect may not be seen if using an orthographic view. All objects drawn *after* the call to glTranslatef() are translated, providing the matrix mode is either GL_MODELVIEW or GL_PROJECTION. So in your example, the previously drawn square should not be effected unless you redraw it.

Comment: I also have confusion about the total width and height w.r.t opengl. I have seen if I use a vertex with -1,-1,0 as x,y,z then it means the bottom left corner. The total width and height of screen can be accessed by using values between -1 and +1. Am I right?